# JIRA connector unable to change status of issue

Tags: flowground

I'm trying to use the JIRA connector to change the status of JIRA issues. After entering the necessary values (issueId, statusName and transitions) I am getting the following error when trying to generate a sample: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`.

Edit Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot luis?

Comment: where are you taking the transitions from? It would be best to take them from the issue itself (by doing a getIssue beforehand, for example). The connector expects the transitions to be an array of objects, each object having a "to" property which itself is an object with a "name" property (this is where the error is generated).

Comment: Screenshot added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Update Status` action needs the whole transitions array. It searches this array for the status name you provide (which can be hardcoded, eg: `"Closed"`). To make it work, just replace `[{"id": transitions[2].id}]` with `transitions` :)